# How to pass route params into apollo / graphql query - Vue/Quasar project. Bad request error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, apollo, quasar

I have followed some different guides to get a vue frontend with a blog, among other things, up and running. The guides uses old versions of apollo, graphgql and vue, while I am using the newest versions (and Quasar instead of pure vue). I have managed to figure most of it out. However I am stuck on getting a query to get executed correctly with the slug from the route params. This is what I got so far:

```
<script>
import { useQuery } from "@vue/apollo-composable";
import gql from "graphql-tag";

export default {
  name: "Post",

  data() {
    return {
      result: null,
    };
  },

  async created() {
    const { result } = await useQuery(gql`
       {
        postBySlug(slug: $slug) {
          id
          title
          content
          featuredImage
          createdAt
          category {
            name
            slug
          }
          tag {
            name
            slug
          }
          user {
            id
            username
            firstName
            lastName
          }
          numberOfLikes
          likes {
            id
          }
          commentSet {
            id
            content
            createdAt
            isApproved
            user {
              username
              avatar
            }
            numberOfLikes
            likes {
              id
            }
          }
        }
        
      }
      
    `, { variables: { slug: this.$route.params.slug }}
     );  

     this.result = result 
  },
};

</script>
```

However, I get a POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql 400 (Bad Request) from the server. I have logged the slug from the route params to the console and it is correct. So i believe that the slug is not being passed into the query correctly for some reason. Any ideas on how to fix it?

I have checked that rest of the query is correct of by running it in the graphql interface in the endpoint.